# Black border jquery cycle IE7-8 transparent PNG

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, jcycle

I am experiencing what seems to be a fairly common situation with IE7-8 not allowing more than one filter at a time. In this case its adding a black border where the transparency is on the png. I have tried all of the suggested fixes including adding the fade transition to parent divs and also the cycle options cleartype: true and cleartypeNoBg: true. I know this is a recurring issue but I can't seem to find an answer that works despite looking.

Please find a working copy here:

http://www.annulus-art.co.uk/index.html

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching this seemed to help a bit, still have a black line at the bottom though.

```
background: transparent !important;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);   /* IE6 & 7 */
    zoom: 1;
```